# Ways to implement P2P Android Messanger

Tags: android, http, p2p

I am totaly new to Android development and not have much experience but want to implement my own P2P messanger. What's way is easiest to do it? I thought to write it using Java sockets or via HTTP.

In my architecture, I want to use a simple HTTP server between peers in order to match a unique username with his ip address and send a message to him.

Comment: this question is extremely broad. you should ask a more specific question related to existing code, instead of seeking a complete solution to a problem

Comment: just wanted to see different opinions from experienced people before starting development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory sockets work fine on android. Although in my experience, there is no guarantee, that the message will be delivered to the client. There are many factors, that might play into the delivery (IP changes, battery-saving policies...).

If you want to make sure, that a message is delivered to the client, and you won't give the message to a third party, I would recommend looking into [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging). 
When you go to the [About FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options) page you will get a overview of the push-types. 
It would be easy for you, to just implement a push-type-patter, where you are receiving a data-push from FCM, which tells the app to pull new messages from your server.

With this method you can make sure, that every message is delivered to the client, but also no one, except your server and your client, can see your message.

Hope I could help!